# Check for cmake before running a make target

Tags: makefile, cmake

I have done the following makefile

```
.PHONY: check
check:
    @[ -f `which cmake` ] ||  $(error Install cmake first)

.PHONY: check2    
check2:
    @[ -f `which cmake` ] || echo "Install cmake first"

.PHONY: exec
exec: check
    @echo "Compiling executable ..."
    @[ -d ./build ] || mkdir ./build
    @cd ./build; cmake ../src; make
```

While target **check2** works (when cmake exists, i don't get the message "Install cmake first", when it doesn't, i get the message), target **check** always exit even when cmake exists.

So I cannot use target **check** for target **exec**. I have to use target **check2** and, of course, *make* quits because it doesn't find cmake.

I would like *make* to quit before it starts echoing "Compiling executable ...".

Answer (score 1):

When make decides it needs to rebuild a target the very first thing it does is expand all the make macros (variables) and functions in the recipe.  Then it sends the resulting, expanded text to the shell.

In the "check" rule you're using the make function $(error ...), so as soon as make decides to build that target it expands the recipe, which includes expanding the $(error ...) function and make exits.  It's not possible for the shell to run one part of the command (like `[ -f ... ]` and then, somehow, indicate to make that it should or shouldn't invoke a make function.

If you want make to fail all you have to do is have your recipe fail.  Your `check2` recipe prints a message but it still succeeds, so it doesn't stop make from continuing on.  You can do this:

```
.PHONY: check2    
check2:
        @[ -f `which cmake` ] || { echo "Install cmake first"; exit 1; }

.PHONY: exec
exec: check2
        @echo "Compiling executable ..."
        @[ -d ./build ] || mkdir ./build
        @cd ./build; cmake ../src; make
```

Alternatively you could just put the test into the exec target itself:

```
.PHONY: exec
exec:
        @[ -f `which cmake` ] || { echo "Install cmake first"; exit 1; }
        @echo "Compiling executable ..."
        @[ -d ./build ] || mkdir ./build
        @cd ./build; cmake ../src; make
```

if you don't need it anywhere else.